# MySQL restoring a database via mysqldump - Does it overwrite the different destination tables?

Tags: backup, mysql, restore

I am using mysqldump to backup a database containing several tables (say tables D, E, F). I use the following command: mysqldump -uuser -ppassword SourceDatabase > file.sql to backup these tables.

I would like to know if I restored this backup, would it overwrite other tables? For example, if I have a database DestinationDatabase, containing tables A, B and C, and after running the command "mysql -uuser -ppassword DestinationDatabase < file.sql", would I lose the tables A, B and C on the destination database (and be left with just D, E and F) or would I be left with A, B, C, D, E and F (with the original tables present in DestinationDatabase left untouched)?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: It depends on whether  the dump does a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` in its first line. I don't think that's the default though. Why not simply try out?

Answer (score 9):

With the default options, it will not delete tables `A`, `B` and `C`. It will however overwrite (delete current data that is not in the backup) tables `D`, `E` and `F`.

To see the list of available options [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the value of the options `add-drop-table` and `add-drop-database` when doing the backup.